# React when to use global variables instead of states

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm putting data loaded from API in a variable declared outside of my function component. I had thought of putting it in a state since it is required to be kept through multiple renders. But I didn't see the purpose since nothing in my code reacts to change to the data.

Would it be an antipattern if I keep using this method to put passive data to be memorized throughout renders?

```
var cityList;
function Component(){
    
    useEffects(async ()=>{
        if (!cityList)}{
            cityList = await loadCities();
        }
    });
    
    ...
}
```

Additionaly I know I can use hooks like `useMemo()`. But I want to know if this has a problem.

Most importantly, What is a possible reason to use variables like this instead of State or memo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you use state instead of a variable outside the component is because of *re-rendering*.

If you do not use state, the *component will not be updated with the new data* returned from your api.

In addition, the correct way to use useEffect is as follows (commented), if you intend to update the data only once.

```
const [ cityList, setCityList ] = useState([]);

function Component(){
    
    useEffects(()=>{      //<-- remove async here as it's not allowed.
        
        const getData = async () => {
              
              const data = await loadCities();
              setCityList(data)

        }
        getData();
    },[]);  //<---- add a empty dependency so it only called once when component mounts
    
    ...
}
```

We usually use variable outside  component if it doesn't change.

```
const initialData = ['a','b','c']

component A = () => {
      // it's fine to use initialData out of the component because it doesn't change.
}
```

Of course, there are also times where we can use variable outside the component that can change over time. But only if the rendering of the component does not depend on it. (e.g. using a global variable to track a setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks @SomeoneReallySpecial! So does this mean I can use such variables fully instead of states as long as I don't need to react when it changes

Comment: Depend on usage really. If it's the situation in your question, you need to use state. State is like the core of React, there's really no reason to avoid using it.

Comment: The negative part of using variable outside component is you are essentially setting it as a global window variable, meaning if you have any scripts using the same global variable then you gonna end up with bugs.

Comment: isn't the variable scope only limited to the component script, since the script is a module?

Comment: I guess you will only see the bug if you bundle compile all your components into one single JS.

Comment: If it does not change, why use `useState` instead of simply declaring `cityList` on its own?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, don't use that method.

You can set a state to keep the values if they can change:

```
function Component() {

    const [cityList, setCityList] = useState()
    
    useEffect(async () => {
        if (!cityList) {
            const response = await loadCities();
            setCityList(response);
        }
    }, [cityList]);
    
    ...
}
```

Check out this example from the React doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#example-using-ajax-results-to-set-local-state

If the data don't change you can declare a variable inside the component:

```
function Component() {

    const cityList = []
        
    ...
}
```

The hook `useMemo` that you have quoted is an optimization. It can be used to avoid unnecesary computations because it stores a memoized value.
`useMemo` is helpful when you have expensive calculations that depends on another values.

Check out the official doc about: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: Thank you, as stated in the question, I knew I could use states. But I wanted to know why not use the previous variable mode, as long as I don't have nothing reacting to change to the data.

Comment: In my opinion state is the appropriate way to store the response of a fetch request. The request take time to get the data so the value change from empty/undefined to your request response (in case of success).

You can also declare a constant inside your component, (if the data won't change) but I think it's not the case.

Comment: Thanks @the_previ ! So does this mean I can use such variables fully instead of states as long as I don't need to react when it changes

Answer (score 0):

One additional issue is that if you use a global variable, when the component gets used elsewhere, that single variable will be accessible to all instances of the components and can be overwritten and the logic mixed, creating unintended coupling.